# Object pointer (this) saved in the constructor for later use seems to have incorrect value

Tags: c++, constructor, this, copy-elision, trivially-copyable

I came across a strange bug today, which basically boils down to the following minimal example:

```
#include <cassert>

struct S* ps;

struct S{
    S(){
        ps = this;
    }
    //~S(){} //(*)
};

S makeS(){
    return S{};
}

int main(){
    S s{makeS()};
    assert(&s == ps);
}
```

With guaranteed copy-elision, I believe that the assertion should never fail. However, when compiled with `-std=c++20` in both gcc 13.1 and clang 16.0, the assertion would fail, as illustrated [here](https://godbolt.org/z/n1esxc6dd). Increasing the optimization level does not help. If I uncomment the line marked `(*)` and add a user-provided destructor, then the assertion no longer fails. Why is that?

**NOTE**: I am intentionally creating a duplicate question for [Copy elision and trivially copyable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381540/copy-elision-and-trivially-copyable-types) as a signpost (which is allowed according to meta) because I have spent very long time before I finally found the answer.

Comment: out of curiosity, could you provide a link to the meta post?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Sure. [Here it is.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307615/should-i-post-a-question-that-im-going-to-immediately-close-as-a-duplicate)